# MySQL Nested or Recursive Query with different tables

Tags: mysql, select, nested, recursive-query

Cordial Greetings.

I have doubts about how to implements queries in MySQL, sorry is too long.

Now:
I have sites that have packs (of different items and quantities) of products.

The Items are stored in the table named **ItemTbl** with 2 fields (IdItem and NameItem)

```
CREATE TABLE ItemTbl ( 
IdItem VARCHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
NameItem VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO ItemTbl (IdItem, NameItem) VALUES 
('Item00','Item 00'), 
('Item01','Item 01'), 
('Item02','Item 02'), 
('Item03','Item 03'), 
('Item04','Item 04'), 
('Item05','Item 05');
```

The Packs are stored in the table named **PackTbl** with 2 fields (IdPack and NamePack)

```
CREATE TABLE PackTbl ( 
IdPack VARCHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
NamePack VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL 
); 
INSERT INTO PackTbl (IdPack, NamePack) VALUES 
('Pack00','Pack 00'), 
('Pack01','Pack 01'), 
('Pack02','Pack 02'), 
('Pack03','Pack 03');
```

The Sites are stored in the table named **SiteTbl** with 2 fields (IdSite and NameSite)

```
CREATE TABLE SiteTbl ( 
IdSite VARCHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
NameSite VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO SiteTbl (IdSite, NameSite) VALUES 
('Site00','Site 00'), 
('Site01','Site 01');
```

The packs are related with items using a table named **ItemPackTbl** having 3 fields (IdItem, IdPack, QtyIP)

```
CREATE TABLE ItemPackTbl ( 
IdItem VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
IdPack VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
QtyIP INT NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO ItemPackTbl (IdItem, IdPack, QtyIP) VALUES 
('Item00', 'Pack00', '90'), 
('Item01', 'Pack00', '81'), 
('Item02', 'Pack00', '72'), 
('Item03', 'Pack01', '63'), 
('Item04', 'Pack01', '54'), 
('Item05', 'Pack01', '50'), 
('Item01', 'Pack02', '61'), 
('Item04', 'Pack02', '72'), 
('Item03', 'Pack03', '83'), 
('Item02', 'Pack03', '94');
```

The sites are related with packs using a table named **PackSiteTbl** having 3 fields (IdPack, IdSite, QtyPS)

```
CREATE TABLE PackSiteTbl ( 
IdPack VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
IdSite VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
QtyPS INT NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO PackSiteTbl (IdPack, IdSite, QtyPS) VALUES 
('Pack00', 'Site00', '5'), 
('Pack03', 'Site00', '4'), 
('Pack01', 'Site01', '8'), 
('Pack02', 'Site01', '1');
```

Now we have a table named **QuotTbl** with different quotations ONLY of Items (because the packs or sites would be calculated) with the cost and date.

```
CREATE TABLE QuotTbl ( 
IdQuot VARCHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
IdItem VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
QtCost INT NOT NULL, 
QtDate DATE NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO QuotTbl (IdQuot, IdItem, QtCost, QtDate) VALUES 
('Quot00', 'Item00', '90', '1983-12-30'), 
('Quot01', 'Item00', '72', '2004-09-09'), 
('Quot02', 'Item01', '63', '2013-02-01'), 
('Quot03', 'Item01', '50', '2012-05-09'), 
('Quot04', 'Item02', '61', '1983-12-30'), 
('Quot05', 'Item02', '27', '2004-09-09'), 
('Quot06', 'Item03', '38', '2013-02-01'), 
('Quot07', 'Item03', '49', '2012-05-09'), 
('Quot08', 'Item04', '90', '1983-12-30'), 
('Quot09', 'Item04', '72', '2004-09-09'), 
('Quot10', 'Item05', '63', '2013-02-01'), 
('Quot11', 'Item05', '50', '2012-05-01');
```

I want to do two things:

1. I need to know what is the queries to obtain the list of entries of **SiteTbl** with a resume of Items (making a addition).

   **Site00** have:

   ```
   ItemId, Qty
   Item00, 450
   Item01, 405
   Item02, 736
   Item03, 332
   ```

   **Site01** have:

   ```
   ItemId, Qty
   Item01, 61
   Item03, 504
   Item04, 504
   Item05, 400
   ```
2. Find the cheapest (or newest) quotation according to QuotTbl Table, with all Items list.

   **Site00** *Cheapest*:

   ```
   ItemId, Qty Cost    Total   
   Item00, 450 72      32400
   Item01, 405 50      20250
   Item02, 736 27      19872
   Item03, 332 38      12616
   ```

   **Site01** *Cheapest*:

   ```
   ItemId, Qty Cost    Total   
   Item01, 61  50      3050
   Item03, 504 38      19152
   Item04, 504 72      36288
   Item05, 400 50      20000
   ```

   **Site00** *Newest*:

   ```
   ItemId, Qty Cost    Total   
   Item00, 450 72      32400
   Item01, 405 63      25515
   Item02, 736 27      19872
   Item03, 332 38      12616
   ```

   **Site01** *Newest*:

   ```
   ItemId, Qty Cost    Total   
   Item01, 61  63      3843
   Item03, 504 38      19152
   Item04, 504 72      36288
   Item05, 400 63      25200
   ```

Thank you for your valuable help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Question:

```
SELECT c.IdItem,b.IdSite, SUM(c.QtyIP*b.QtyPS) Multiply
FROM PackSiteTbl b 
LEFT JOIN ItemPackTbl c
ON b.IdPack = c.IdPack 
GROUP BY b.IdSite, c.IdItem;
```

Cheapest

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT IdQuot, IdItem, QtCost Cheapest 
FROM QuotTbl
ORDER BY QtCost ASC) d
GROUP BY IdItem;
```

Newest

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT IdQuot, IdItem, QtCost Newest
FROM QuotTbl
ORDER BY QtDate DESC) d
GROUP BY IdItem;
```

Check this answer in: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/444b7/66